# how to rotate the picture made with Python Turtle to turn left by 90 degrees?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I want to rotate the spider in this hexagon to the left by 90 degrees.
I've tried "setheading(heading() + 90)"but it is not working well.

Here's my code

```py
from turtle import *
from math import *
from random import *
pensize(3)
speed(5)
hideturtle()

#Draw a hexagon
fillcolor('light green')
penup()                       
goto(-150, 300) 
pendown()                    
begin_fill()

#use loop to draw 6 times
for i in range(6):
forward(300)  
right(60)    
end_fill()

#start to draw a spider
fillcolor('black')


def lower_body():
penup()
goto(0,-50)
pendown()
begin_fill()
circle(100)
end_fill()
penup()

#Draw spider's upper body
def upper_body():
goto(125,0)
pendown()
begin_fill()
circle(50)
end_fill()
penup()

#Draw spider's right leg
def right_leg():
goto(70,-20)
pendown()
color("black")
right(45)
forward(80)
right(90)
forward(60)
penup()

goto(15,-20)
pendown()
color("black")
left(85)
forward(100)
right(100)
forward(60)
penup()

goto(-25,-20)
pendown()
color("black")
left(80)
forward(100)
right(90)
forward(60)
penup()

goto(-55,-20)
pendown()
color("black")
left(70)
forward(100)
right(90)
forward(60)
penup()

#Draw spider's left leg
def left_leg():
home()
goto(70,120)
pendown()
color("black")
left(45)
forward(80)
left(90)
forward(60)
penup()

goto(15,120)
pendown()
color("black")
right(85)
forward(100)
left(100)
forward(60)
penup()

goto(-25,120)
pendown()
color("black")
right(80)
forward(100)
left(90)
forward(60)
penup()

goto(-55,120)
pendown()
color("black")
right(70)
forward(100)
left(90)
forward(60)
penup()

#Draw spider's eyes
def spider_eye():
home()
goto(140, 10)
color("white")
begin_fill()
circle(10)
end_fill()
penup()

goto(140, 70)
color("white")
begin_fill()
circle(10)
end_fill()
penup()


def spider():
setheading(heading()+90)
lower_body()`your text`
upper_body()
right_leg()
left_leg()
spider_eye()

spider() # Call the spider function to draw the complete spider
```

What code should I add to solve my problem?

Comment: Can you [edit] the post to format your code's indentation please? Thanks.

Comment: The heading will only work, if you exclusively use forward, left, right, etc. However, your code uses a lot of goto with absolute coordinates, so you have to recalculate each of those coordinates for the rotated spider.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @ggorlen thank you, first time using stack overflow, sorry for that

Comment: @treuss, so should I get rid of goto, and try to use forward, left, right only?

Comment: That's right. If you only use forward, right, left and avoid goto and heading then you can draw your pattern at any position looking any way by once using goto and heading before starting drawing.